# Definite Integral involving exponentials and arbitrary powers

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I have the following integral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} \frac1{(k_1t + 1)^s}\frac1{(k_2t + 1)^s}\mathrm dt$$

where $k_1>0$, $k_2>0$ and $s>0$. How would you suggest to solve it?

Comment: What's the context here?  Why do you believe that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: I need a closed form expression if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that: 
\begin{align}{\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\exp{-t}\,%
{1 \over ({kt + 1})^{s}}\,dt}
&={\exp({1 \over 2k})k^{({1 - z - s})/2}\
\Gamma({z}){\rm W}_{({1 - z -s})/2,\ ({z - s})/2}({1 \over k})}
\end{align}
where W is the  .